# Fixed div with 100%

Tags: jquery, css

I have fixed div with 100% height. But when I scroll I want to see footer. How can I do it height 100% when I don't see footer and from top to footer when I scroll to footer?

http://jsfiddle.net/9fCfE/ - this my code. I need - fixed div must be always on top and shouldn't cover the footer.

```
    .fixed {
    width: inherit;
    height: 95%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    }
    footer {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

(Sorry, my English not very well)

Comment: 100% height relative to what? document? body? container?

Comment: 100% for document. <body><div style="position:fixed; top:0; height: 100%; overflow: auto">big text with scroll</div></body>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9fCfE/ - this my code. I need - fixed div must be always on top and shouldn't cover the footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this **as like this**

```
html, body{
height:100%;
}
.wraper{
background:red;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/bn0e48nE)

### -----------------

Second option is **define** `fixed position`

as like this

```
.wraper{
background:red;
position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;overflow:scroll;
}
```

**[Demo-2](http://tinkerbin.com/7qqoWb6v)**

Comment: I mean - good example - https://delicious.com/ with right block. But I have end of page and footer. Page more bigger then div with 100% height

Answer (score 0):

Here is a css demo i believe is close to what you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
     padding: 0;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0 0 150px 0;
}
footer {
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}

.content{
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/DPhaJ/

Otherwise you'll need JavaScript if you want to alter your html and/or styles on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you want :  http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/9fCfE/8/

slight CSS change:

```
.fixed {
    background: red;
    width: inherit;
    /*  height: 95%;*/
    top:0;
    bottom:5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and JS:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $footer = $('footer');
var $fixed = $('.fixed');

function adjustHeight() {
    var wHeight = $window.height() + 0;
    var originalBottom = wHeight * .05;

    var bottom = wHeight - ($footer.offset().top - $window.scrollTop() + 0);

    bottom = Math.max(originalBottom, bottom);
    $fixed.css({
            'bottom': bottom
    });

};

$(window).scroll(adjustHeight)
```